# Hiding my Azure VM from Public

Tags: azure, access-control-list

I have an active on production azure cloud service with couple of web roles running an ASP .NET MVC application, each role has few VMs.

I recently added a Linux machine running a redis server to boost performance, and I want to hide this server(s) from the world, currently the VM has a public IP that can be used to connect directly to it.

I saw ACL configuration, but it requires me to allow IP ranges (CIDR), but I don't know how to figure out the ranges of my web roles

Anyone has an idea of how to totally remove the public IP or how to figure out the IP ranges of my web roles that would be great.

Comment: Seems odd that this question was closed, as it appears to be valid (and makes sense to me): Connecting cloud services (web roles) and a VM (in this case, a redis server) either requires a public endpoint to be opened on the redis VM (since traffic jumps the cloud service boundary) or some type of vnet to be used. This, in my opinion, is a valid question that should be re-opened. And, once re-opened, I'll post an additional answer regarding the ACL approach.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a Virtual Network (VNet) into your environment and join all machines (even the Web Roles) to it.

This way you can deploy the Linux VM and close all its public Endpoints and only use the private IP address range you assigned to it as the conncetion IP on your Web Roles.  There is some [good guidance online](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/06/02/connecting-cloud-services-with-virtual-machines-in-windows-azure/) on achieving this configuration.